# Counting amount of base records in (My)Sql 1-to-many relation

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables:

- invoices (contains id field)
- contracts (contains fk to invoice + 'code' field)

Let's say I have one record in the invoices table and two records in the contracts table. Both records in the contracts table point to the same invoice record.

**Desire**: I'd like to count the amount of invoices.

What I've got so far:

```
select
    c.code, count(*)
from
    invoices i
join
    contracts c
on
    c.invoice_id = i.id
group by  
    c.code
```

Although the count shows **two** instead of the desired **1**. I understand that this is because of the join on the contract table, but not sure how to fix this.

Comment: For a code, there is one invoice as per your sample data. You are thinking the problem other way around. It should be, for a particular invoice, there are two codes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with COUNT(DISTINCT i.id); it should count the different invoice id's in the resultset.

```
select
    c.code, count(distinct i.id)
from
    invoices i
join
    contracts c
on
    c.invoice_id = i.id
group by  
    c.code
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the number of invoices?

```
select count(*)
from invoices i
```

You want invoices with contracts?

```
select count( distinct c.invoice_id)
from
contracts
```

Your code finds number of contracts per each invoice